# Best approach to disable link resolving?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I understand that in a SDL Tridion 2011 implementation, there are two possibilities for disabling link resolving. So when a component is published, not all linked components will also be republished.

These two ways are:

- Using the **Event system**, by subscribing to a Publish Event and modifying the resolve instructions like this:

```cs
args.PublishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks = false;
```

- Using a custom resolver and implementing the `Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Resolving.IResolver` Interface

The question is: Which one of these options is prefered and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that the Event System is the most efficient. The resolver will work, but you will be "post-processing" the resolved items. By this I mean that you will be filtering items out of the publish transaction which have been added by the default resolver. The even system will prevent this links being resolved in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that if there is no specific logic on what components not to resolve. E.g. Resolve some linked components and not others. The Event System is most efficient